# Does classical mechanics implicitly assume short-range forces?

Tags: classical-mechanics, foundations

If you take an axiomatic view of Classical Mechanics and the concept mass as primitive in this context, you could derive from Newton's laws an operational way of determining masses simply by arbitrarily assigning a mass to an object and demanding momentum conservation in its interactions with other objects. But if there are interactions that increase as a function of distance, this method ceases to be practical. Does this imply that an axiomatic theory should include the prescription that forces decay with distance?

Comment: I would not say short-rage forces, but forces vanishing with the distance. Gravitational force is in no way a short-range force. Still, it decays with the distance.

Comment: If we lived inside the earth, in big caves, the force of gravity would increase linearly with altitude. But all experiments with objects moving horizontally on low friction surfaces would result in the same law of momentum conservation.

Comment: As usual with Classical Mechanics, it is not easy to reply meaningfully without specifying the assumed form of the three laws. In particular, how do you define forces?

Comment: > *an axiomatic view of Classical Mechanics* which one? Btw. defining mass based on "we want conservation of momentum $\sum m\mathbf v$" is very artificial in mechanics. Mass in basic physics is defined through amount of matter, or weight. Only relativistic theories give a good reason to re-evaluate that (inertial mass of a composite body needs not be sum of inertial masses of the particles).

Answer (score 0):

The laws of motion simply DONT CARE what the force is or where it comes from , it just says that momentum is conserved for all closed systems and if it changes then there must be something which makes it change,it cant change by its own "will".This is what Newton had in mind.Newton didnt know about atoms or electromagnetism.Coulomb lived 70 years later than Newton.Newton only knew about 1 force:gravity.

Comment: It is false that Newton only knew about gravity. He knew magnets very well; at his time, Hooke proposed his linear law for elastic forces, and the same investigation about gravitational force started from the problem of determining which kind of force would be consistent with elliptic orbits. Therefore, the possibility of different laws for the forces was quite clear to Newton. Moreover, it is not so simple to argue that Newton's laws are entirely independent of hypotheses about the dependence of forces on distances.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 sure but the point is that Newton defined Force = Change in momentum.He didnt seem to care about the origin of the force.

Answer (score 0):

If you take "classical mechanics" and added in the assumption of relativistic invariance, I think you would get your conclusion.  In fact, that conclusion would go even further than yours.  It would apply to all classical physics (electromagnetism, etc.), and wouldn't merely require a force that *decays* with distance, but rather a requirement that all forces were extremely short range, as small as the scale of the objects you were modeling.  In order to locally conserve energy and momentum, any long-range interactions would then necessarily be mediated through short-range interactions (presumably via fields).  If you were to abstract away the fields, the resulting apparent at-a-distance forces would indeed generally decay with distance, simply because of how fields spread out from a source over a large distance.

The justification for these claims is that in a relativistically-invariant model, direct long-range forces have a simultaneity problem.  You can't say the moon is attracted to the Earth's position "right now", if "right now" is frame-dependent.  This problem is resolved with in Einstein's general relativity via local interactions between matter and spacetime.  Similar resolutions occur for long-range Coulomb and Lorentz forces in E+M, which use electromagnetic fields as local intermediaries.

Given relativistic invariance, you can write down equations for localized energy-density and momentum-density conservation (technically, in terms of the Stress-Energy tensor, $\nabla_\nu T^{\mu\nu} =0)$.  From this, along with the map from fields and particles to $ T^{\mu\nu}$, you can get Newton's Laws.  Or as you put it, by demanding energy-momentum conservation, and also demanding Newton's Laws, it seems like you could determine the appropriate map from fields and particles to $ T^{\mu\nu}$, allowing an operational definition of mass, energy, momentum, etc.

Answer (score 0):

At the quantum level, forces adhere to the inverse square law due to the dispersion of radiating quanta. These individual quanta retain their energy across all distances, but their collective intensity diminishes as the encompassing sphere expands.

The determination of an object's mass by arbitrary assigning a mass and demanding momentum, faces challenges in the realm of quantum mechanics. This is due to the acknowledgment that quantum mechanics designates photons as lacking mass.